# How do I make define and declare a variable using the default constructor in C++?

Tags: c++, constructor, default-constructor

From my understanding of declarations and definitions, at the global scope:

```
MyClass instance();//Declares a function that returns a MyClass
MyClass instance;//Declares an instance of MyClass
```

Is it possible to declare a variable and define it to use the default constructor at global scope? What if I was using a structure instead of a class?

**EDIT:**

Okay, so `MyClass instance;` does call the default constructor. Can anyone explain how this is consistent with [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936999/what-is-the-default-constructor-for-c-pointer/937257#937257):

```
int a; // not default constructed, will have random data 
int b = int(); // will be initialised to zero
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
MyClass instance;
```

will invoke the default constructor (i.e. the constructor with no parameters).

This is counter-intuitive, because to invoke an overloaded constructor with parameters you would do the following:

```
MyClass instance(param1, param2);
```

Logic would tell you that you pass in an empty argument list to invoke the default constructor, but the following code...

```
MyClass instance();
```

...looks like a prototype to the compiler rather than the construction of a `MyClass` object.

There is no difference between a `struct` and a `class` in C++, except that a `struct` has `public` members by default and a `class` has `private` members by default.

Comment: Why does this behave differently from how `int` works (see edit above)?

Comment: @Casebash - `int` is a POD type, which will either be zero-initialized or uninitialized depending on how it is declared.  When you declare an `int` locally on the stack and don't explicitly initialize it, it will have random data as you have indicated.  Please see this answer for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102096/when-do-c-pod-types-get-zero-initialized/3102134#3102134

Comment: Suppose `MyStruct` is defined as `struct MyStruct { int a;};`. The answer you linked to seems to imply that `MyStruct` is not default initialised if it is declared in local scope (it says that myInstance.a is undefined). The default constructor for a struct calls the default constructors for each element in the structure, right?

Comment: @Casebash - Yes, the default constructor for a `struct` or `class` will default-initialize all members.

Comment: @LeopardSkinPillBoxHat [how to do `MyClass instance;` if the constructor of `MyClass` requires arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67550551)?

Comment: @user2284570 - I wrote this answer 11 years ago when I was writing C++ regularly but I'm a bit out of practice with this, and C++ has changed heaps since I was using it.  So I'd probably trust the people answering on your other question more than me :-)

Answer (score 2):

1. It doesn't matter whether you're at global scope or not.
2. `MyClass instance;` is a definition (using the default constructor, not just a declaration. To get only a declaration (e.g. in a header file), you would use `extern MyClass instance;`.
3. It doesn't matter, for this part, whether `MyClass` is a class or a struct. The **only** thing that changes between structs and classes in C++ is the default interpretation of whether members and bases are public or private.
4. If you want to be explicit, you could write `MyClass instance = MyClass();`.

Answer (score 1):

```
MyClass instance;
```

is also a definition, using the default constructor. If you want to merely declare it you need

```
extern MyClass instance;
```

which is not a definition. Both, however, have external linkage.

Comment: [how to do `MyClass instance;` if the constructor of `MyClass` requires arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67550551)?