# Linked List - pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, linked-list, nodes

I created a linked list and when I tried to print values of the nodes and used NULL as a bound, it didn't work. For example:

```
#include <iostream>

typedef struct Node;
typedef Node* Node_ptr;
struct Node
{
    int i;
    Node_ptr next;
};

int main()
{
    Node_ptr ptr, head;
    ptr = new Node;
    head = ptr;

    // load
    for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    {
        ptr->next = new Node;
        ptr->i = j;
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }

    // print
    ptr = head;
    while(ptr->next != NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "print: " << ptr->i << std::endl;
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
}
```

However, when I run this code, the code gets stuck in an endless loop in the while loop.
It never understands that the linked list is only 5 nodes long, it just keeps on going. I can't understand why that happens.

Comment: That's not valid C or C++ code.  There's missing semicolons, and a stray `typedef`, missing `}`...

Comment: You're checking for NULL but have you set it anywhere?

Comment: ..and when you've fixed that, you need to do some debugging.

Comment: Not counting the missing quote after print. And `ptr = ptr->next` obviously causes an endless loop as `ptr` equals `ptr->next` so the while loop never moves any further... Please show us your real code.

Comment: Now that the question has been answered, I have edited the code so that it is valid, and yet still illustrates the root cause of the problem

Comment: @dark_charlie: `ptr = ptr->next` is a fairly standard way of looping through elements in a linked list. I don't see anything wrong with *that* part of the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably just need to initialize your pointers (to NULL), otherwise they'll just contain garbage, and will thus also appear as being valid pointers.

For instance:

```
for(j = 0; j < 4; j++)
{
   ptr->next = new Node;
   (ptr->next)->next = NULL;
   ptr->i = j;
   ptr = ptr->next;
}
```

Comment: +1 for identifying the cause of the problem. However, I would lean towards using a constructor rather than setting `(ptr->next)->next = NULL;` manually.

Comment: @e.James you don't need a constructor to initialize POD types. See my suggestion.

Comment: @Luchian : I upvoted your answer, but to be fair, a constructor would certainly make things less error-prone (unless the OP needs his type to be a C++03 POD for some reason).

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Point taken, and I upvoted your answer as well. Although, tecnically speaking, adding those parentheses is just invoking the default constructor, isn't it?

Comment: @e.James : `Node` is a POD type, so there is no default constructor; `new Node` uses _default-initialization_, which would already invoke the default constructor if there was one. Adding the parenthesis _value-initializes_ the object, which in turn effectively zero-initializes its data members.

Comment: @ildjarn: Cool. That makes sense. I'll stand by my initial position which was to prefer a constructor, because you never know when `Node` will stop being a POD class.

Comment: For reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102096/when-do-c-pod-types-get-zero-initialized

Comment: @e.James : Value-initialization works on non-POD types too. ;-] See §8.5 in the C++ standard for the full list of semantics.

Answer (score 4):

Try value initializing your `Node`:

```
ptr = new Node();
```

instead of

```
ptr = new Node;
```

Otherwise, you'll just have garbage in the members.

Comment: Oh, that's a much simpler solution then isn't it?

Answer (score 3):

```
while(ptr->next != NULL)
```

You clearly coded it to continue until `ptr->next` is `NULL`.  Maybe you should set `ptr->next` to `NULL` for at least one item in the list?  This is why it is common in `C` to `memset(&object, 0, sizeof(object));`, or in `C++` to have a constructor.

```
typedef struct Node
{
  int i;
  Node* next;
  Node() : i(0), next(NULL) {} //prevents this problem
}
```