# C++ Private structure and non static const variables initialization

Tags: c++, class, struct, heap-memory

I totally disappointed. I have class, there I have private structure. And what's the silly problem: I just can't preinitialize some variables! 
What I mean: 
I need:

```
struct someStruct
    {
        someStruct *next = NULL;
        int number;
    };
```

I just want to create easy dynamic list, adding new elements from heap. 
And what I should do?

```
struct someStruct
    {
        someStruct *next;
        int number;
    };
```

Put

```
someStruct *newElement = new someStruct;
newElement.next = NULL;
```

every time? I can forget about this.

Please help me. Because it's not a problem when I need to add 1 useless string. But what if I have 50 default variables?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102096/when-do-c-pod-types-get-zero-initialized

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot initialize class members when you declare them. Instead, you need a *constructor*:

```
struct someStruct {
    someStruct(): next(NULL), number(0) {}
    someStruct *next;
    int number;
};
```

Alternatively, for [POD (plain old data)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620137/do-the-parentheses-after-the-type-name-make-a-difference-with-new/620402#620402), you could use your original class with no constructors and use `someStruct *newElement = new someStruct();` to create a `someStruct`. This initializes the members to zero.

Also, C++11 supports [in-class member initializers](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#member-init).

Comment: Alternatively, initialize a the point of declaration in C++11.

Comment: Alternative 2: `someStruct *newElement = new someStrsomeStruct();`, requires no modification to the original class.

Comment: @Destiner You can find a list of supported C++11 features at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh567368.aspx. Currently, Non-static data member initializers aren't supported.